# Which Live CD Linux distros have Chrome preinstalled

Tags: linux, google-chrome, livecd

Which Linux distros that have live CD (or live USB) come with Chrome browser preinstalled ?

If you mention distros that do NOT have Chrome preinstalled,
it also helps :-). Because it narrows the search.

Tried Linux Mint 11; no Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Not in Ubuntu, Debian or Fedora.

Answer (score 4):

Lubuntu comes with chromium (open source version of chrome) preinstalled. Here's a link:

http://lubuntu.net. I am being unable to connect to their website right now, so here's a

better link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Applications

Answer (score 3):

Most of the Linux distributions tend to come with Firefox preinstalled. I have not seen one with Chrome, other than ChromeOS of course if you count that as a Linux distro.

Comment: [Cr OS Linux](http://getchrome.eu) comes with Chrome/ium preinstalled.

Answer (score 3):

The only Linux distro I know of that comes with Chrome as the browser is Chrome OS Linux.  This is not to be confused with Chronium OS from Google.  This is a distro that comes with Chrome as the browser.

Get the Live CD from:  http://getchrome.eu/download.php

Comment: Chrome OS Linux is now called Cr OS Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any distro that comes with Chrome by default. However, there are a few distros that allow you to select packages to include in your liveCD on the website and then allow you to download your custom liveCD.

An example is [Slax](http://www.slax.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html) v6.7.1 (and current versions) have Chromium installed.

Currently (August 2013), only the DVD has it. See the [CD](ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/knoppix/packages-cd.txt) and [DVD](ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/knoppix-dvd/packages-dvd.txt) package lists.

Comment: Answer seems a little light. Perhaps you could add a link to the Knoppix download?